# PHP sizeof() returns 1 incorrectly

Tags: php, sizeof

This code worked last week, and I don't remember changing this code recently, but for some reason it stopped working today.

I've narrowed down the issue, but I'm confused about it. Basically, `$fields = sizeof($dataArray[$r]);` yields `$fields = 1`, but as you can see in the image below, `ECHO json_encode($dataArray);` demonstrates that `$fields = 9` should be observed.

```
$dataArray = $_POST['array'];

$validRows = array();
$invalidRows = array();

echo sizeof($dataArray); // correct output

for($r = 0; $r < sizeof($dataArray); $r++){

  $fields = sizeof($dataArray[$r]); // $fields is not what I expect

  ECHO json_encode($dataArray); // see image below (sent to javaScript alert)
  ECHO sizeof($fields); // returns 1
 
  ...
}
```

`ECHO json_encode($dataArray);` Seen in a javaScript alert

[image]

**What's my issue here?**

Comment: `print_r($dataArray);`

Comment: That image is print_r($dataArray);

Comment: your count each array 'key->var', so 1 makes perfect sense to me

Comment: @Dagon I don't understand

Comment: your count is inside the loop, of each element of the array

Comment: This is because you show us `json_encode` of something. What are the keys in original array? Are they numeric?

Comment: $_POST['array']; comes from JavaScript, i believe the keys automatically become numeric when assigned to the array in php

Comment: You are doing nested `sizeof()`, and echoing the result of the outer `sizeof()` -> `$fields = sizeof($dataArray[$r]); ... ECHO sizeof($fields);` is basically doing `ECHO sizeof(sizeof($dataArray[$r]));`, and since the inner `sizeof()` would return a single value, the outer will return 1.

Comment: @Sean - That was it! Add an answer and I will credit you.

Comment: i said that oh 20 minutes ago ;)

Comment: @Dagon My apologies. I didn't understand you that way. Which Comment? I can give it to you if you post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on PHP Documentation, sizeOf (alias of Count) returns 1 if the array is not countable .

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

> Returns the number of elements in array_or_countable. If the parameter
>   is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface,
>   1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is
>   NULL, 0 will be returned.

But appart from that, on your second ECHO, you are displaying the sizeOff ot the result of a sizeoff , that would be a single number
pseudo:
a = count("a","b","c")
a should be 3
ECHO count(a)
ECHO Display 1, as (a) is a single element

Comment: I don't understand. Why is it not countable? where do I use "sizeoff"?

Comment: $fields its just a number, so when you count it , its return that its only one number.  Change the last line from 
ECHO sizeof($fields);
to :
ECHO $fields;